# Android N: My app call onDestroy() when entering multi-windows mode

Tags: android

Sirs,

I've made a brand new project and added

```
 "android:resizeableActivity="true"
```

in the manifest.xml.

Then adding Logs in lifecycle method(`onStart(), onResume(), onStop()...`)

After that, use the simulator to run my app on Android N(API 24)(6.x).

I've found when my app is in the front, long pressing the recent button to enter multi-windows mode, the log prints

> onPause()->onStop()->**onDestroy()**->onStart()->onResume()->onPause()

Is that correct? or may I do mistakes?

If it is correct, can I detect if the app really ends up or it goes to multi-windows mode in `onDestroy()`?

Thus, I can prevent some objects destroy when entering multi-windows mode.

Comment: Alright. I've found I can check `Activity.inMultiWindow()` to know that and the app must restart on changing multi-window mode. That's too bad!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Adding screenLayout to android:configChanges in manifest.xml should solve the issue.

Comment: Thanks, bro. I'll try it later:)

Answer (score 2):

The only way it works for me is *screenLayout* and *smallestScreenSize* set to `android:configChanges` in *manifest.xml*.

Answer (score 0):

From documentation:

> Note: To handle all Multi-Window related configuration changes use
>   both "screenLayout" and "smallestScreenSize". Multi-Window is
>   supported in Android 7.0 (API level 24) or higher.

Therfore, you should use

```
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|screenLayout|smallestScreenSize"
```

in your `<activity` manifest